# EF Core 8 HasDefaultValue for bool (bit in database) is not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, fluent

I am upgrading a web application from .NET Core 2.1 to .NET 8 and, besides problems with the Nullable setting, now I have a new problem:  all the default settings for `BIT` column types (`boolean` in C# code) are not working anymore when adding new records.

The settings for these columns are the following (using Fluent API):

```
builder.Entity<Product>(db =>
{
    db.Property(ss => ss.IsActive).HasDefaultValue(true);
});
```

The field declaration in the class is the following:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Display(Name = "Status")]
public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

The setting for `DateTime` columns works without problems.

Are there any changes regarding this setting that I missed? I searched for answers, but I didn't find anything relevant.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: This is a known issue for EF Core: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21664  Check the references for work-arounds.

Comment: There is some (breaking) behavior change in EF8, which is supposed to solve the non intuitive behavior of bool properties with `HasDefalutValue(true)`. See [Database defaults for booleans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew#database-defaults-for-booleans) in [What's New in EF Core 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew)

Comment: @ErikEJ it means it doesn't add the default value I set in the Fluent PI code (see above), which should be TRUE. If I don't assign any value to this field, when I add a new record the value for the field IsActive is FALSE.

Comment: @StevePy the code is working if I stick with the code that's using .NET Core 2.1.14 (EF Core included). The problem appeared after I upgraded to .NET 8.

Comment: EF Core has changed quite a bit from 2.1. The bug probably has to do with optimizations. Try taking EF Core back to EF Core 7 and see if that addresses it if the breaking change was with EF Core 8. While it is good to keep up with the latest "release", modern OSS is more a case of a continual open Beta where you have the privilege of doing the testing. The only certainty of staying on the bleeding edge is that you are going to get bloody. :)